# Node mysql query not updating variable from outside the query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to get a return value from this code with no luck. Everything I put inside the mysql query function becomes undefined for some reason. I directly returning the value from inside the query, getting the query to manipulate a variable value outside of it and directly assigning it into a variable. I'm out of ideas

1.)

```
connection.query(sql, response = (err,rows) => {
   if(row = condition){
     return something;
   }
}
```

2.)

```
var something
connection.query(sql, response = (err,rows) => {
   if(row = condition){
     something = somerow;
   }
}
```

3.)

```
var myvar =connection.query(sql, response = (err,rows) => {
   if(row = condition){
     return something;
   }
}
```

None of these works.Number 3 returns some jibberish JSON. What can i do? Also, this is the structure of the function, if it will help.

Model:

```
exports.Something = () => {

    connection.query(sql, response = (err,rows) => {


     }

   return anything

}
```

Controller:

```
exports.Thing = (req,res) =>{
    var response = UserModel.Something();
    return res.send(response);
}
```

Comment: The data is at `rows` and you are printing `row`? Also you are using `=` instead of `===` in a condition

Comment: That wasnt the actual code sorry. Everything works fine if i just render it directly and put it in the app.js. But I need to implement MVC and i cant seem to get anything out of the mysql query. I tried console logging it and it's there. The problem is that I cant return it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to return something from `callback` which doesn't work. You can either use callback like:

```
exports.Something = (callback) => {
  connection.query(sql, response = (err,rows) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err)
    } else {
      callback(null, rows)
    }
  })
}

// In you controller
exports.Thing = (req,res) =>{
  var response = UserModel.Something((err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
      console.error(err)
    } else {
      res.send(rows);
    }
  });
}
```

Or use `Promise` and `async/await` like:

```
exports.Something = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(sql, response = (err,rows) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(rows)
      }
    })
  })
}

// In you controller
// make the middleware async function
exports.Thing = async (req,res) =>{
  try {
    var rows = await UserModel.Something()
    return res.send(rows);
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

With `async/await` you handle error in `try..catch` block.